# what is wrong with the hibernate mapping xml?

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, hibernate-mapping

As I validate the following `xml`, I get the following error :

```
The content of element type "class" must match "(meta*,subselect?,cache?,
synchronize*,comment?,tuplizer*,(id|composite-id),
discriminator?,natural-id?,(version|timestamp)?,
(property|many-to-one|one-to-one|component|dynamic-component|properties|any|map
|set|list|bag|idbag|array|primitive-array)*,((join*,subclass*)|joined-subclass*|
union-subclass*),loader?,sql-insert?,sql-update?,sql-delete?,filter*,resultset*,
(query|sql-query)*)". [16]
```

---

What could be the reason I am getting this ?

```
 <hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="pojo.Parent" table="student_detail">
      <id name="roll_number">
          <generator class="increment" />
      </id>
      <property name="s_name" />
      <discriminator column="discrim" type="string" />
      <subclass name="pojo.Child">
          <property name="hindi" />
          <property name="english" />
          <property name="punjabi" />
          <property name="total" />
      </subclass>
  </class>    
  </hibernate-mapping>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of the elements is wrong.

Put the `discriminator` immediately after the `id`.

Take a look at the example [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html).

Comment: why does the order matter ?

Comment: Why does that matter? The point is that it does and the file will not validate unless the order is correct. Maybe when hibernate reads the mappings its easier to read the discriminator first?